# $\frac{t_1 + y}{s_1} \leq \frac{t_2 + y}{s_2}$ and $\frac{t_1}{s_1} \leq \frac{t_2}{s_2}$

Tags: inequality

Consider the following inequality
$\frac{t_1 + y}{s_1} \leq \frac{t_2 + y}{s_2}$ where $y$ is a non-negative integer and others are positive integers, does this imply $\frac{t_1}{s_1} \leq \frac{t_2}{s_2}$ and if yes how? if not why not?

Comment: Have you tried some values?

Comment: Nope, I was trying to solve it generally

Comment: Since it holds if both $s$ are equal, try for example $t_1=s_1=1$ and $t_2=s_2=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{t_1 + y}{s_1} \leq \frac{t_2 + y}{s_2}\implies \frac{t_1 }{s_1} \leq \frac{t_2}{s_2}+y\left(\frac1{s_2}-\frac1{s_1}\right)$$

- If $s_2\ge s_1$, then $y(1/s_2-1/s_1)\le0$ which gives $t_1/s_1\le t_2/s_2$.
- If $s_2< s_1$, then for $y\ne0$ we have $y(1/s_2-1/s_1)>0$ and the result is not necessarily true unless $y=0$. For example, take $t_1=s_1=8,t_2=2,s_2=4,y=64$.

Comment: For the first part, if we subtract negative it may not be greater or equal to it, are you sure about this part "- If $s_2\ge s_1$, then $y(1/s_2-1/s_1)\le0$ which gives $t_1/s_1\le t_2/s_2$.
"?

Comment: @AlexJ We are subtracting negative from the RHS. In other words, $t_1/s_1$ is smaller than (or equal to) some quantity which is less than (or equal to) $t_2/s_2$, so $t_1/s_1$ is definitely smaller than (or equal to) $t_2/s_2$. Kinda like saying $3\le5-1$ so $3$ is definitely less than (or equal to) $5$.

Comment: Oh I wanted to say if you add negative number it may not be greater, for example 5 <= 7 but 5 <= 7 - 3 is not right.

Comment: @AlexJ You are talking about the converse. $5\le7$ does not imply $5\le7-3$, but $5\le7-1$ does imply $5\le7$, which is what I have actually used here. Note that $\frac{t_1 }{s_1} \leq \frac{t_2}{s_2}+y\left(\frac1{s_2}-\frac1{s_1}\right)$ is given to us already in the problem. So if the $y$ term is negative, the LHS is smaller than some number less than $t_2/s_2$ so it is indeed smaller than $t_2/s_2$.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. If you are satisfied with my answer, consider accepting it by clicking the tick-mark button next to it.